# Changing an ASP.net contact form into PHP

Tags: php, asp.net, html, wordpress, contact-form

I recently redid my company's website, the old site was an ASP.net site, I rebuilt the site in PHP (With wordpress) The contact form on the old site submitted the fields to a database, I rebuilt a contact form with the wordpress backend. The problem is that the contact form doesn't submit the fields to a database on a separate server than the website. How can I best carry this feature into the PHP/Wordpress framework?

I'm using Contact Form 7, with the contact form 7 to database plugin right now.

I can post my code if needed.

Comment: We can't really help you without seeing code and information about what is not working.

Comment: There are plenty of feedback and form plugins for WP.  I suggest you get one and use one instead of home-cooking your own.

Comment: @EliGassert that would be assuming that the table the old form used to add entries too isn't being used by more than 1 person. Some random plugin will mean it will be entered into a new table and not the old one.

Comment: @RyanMcDonough his question states *the contact form doesn't submit the fields to a database* -- it's pretty generic.  He says *a database* not *my old table*.  I think you're making the assumption that he wants to retain the old ASP.NET DB in his new Wordpress site.  That seems highly unlikely.  I realize that it backs up your answer and thus why you argue for it, but I still remain that it is probably not the case.  I have no issue if that is the case and I hope he awards you points if you've assumed correctly.  But from the question, I don't see it being the case.

Comment: @EliGassert ah I see what you mean, apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So rather than using a wordpress contact form plugin or one built into wordpress you will need to build your own if you intend for it to go directly into the same database as before.

Follow the guide on [this website](http://brian.dobberteen.com/code/using-php-and-mysql-to-create-a-simple-contact-form-and-results-browser/) to create a contact form that will insert into a database, obviously renaming the fields in the query for the database you want to fill.

If you are wanting to store the data from a wordpress plugin such as Contact 7 into a database then I suggest [this plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/contact-form-7-to-database-extension/)

Comment: That plugin you mentioned on the last paragraph would work, but my boss says the database CANNOT be on the same server as the website, so I have the added challenge of writing to a database on a different server,

Comment: Using wordpress that is not an issue you can reference a database on a different server? Are have you got wordpress database on the same server as the site and the contact db on another server?

Comment: Yes the contact database needs to be on another server than the wordpress database. The contact form needs to put the fields in a table on a database on the other server.

Comment: Right then you will need to create option 1 in my answer, and host that form in an iframe on the contact page on the wordpress install.